# Scope Tests Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, scope, activemodel

How do I test a scope on a read-only Active Model on Rails 5?

One of the scopes I have:

```
scope :hauptdiagnose_filter, ->(hauptdiagnose) {
joins(:patient_icd)
    .where('patient_icds.rank = 1')
    .where('patient_icds.code ~ ?', Util.build_regex(hauptdiagnose)) unless hauptdiagnose.blank?}
```

Comment: What behavior do you want to assert/verify? Do you have a test database with known data to verify the return results?

Comment: I want to verify the correct `patients` are returned when the scope is applied, and yes I do have a database with known data.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what values the scope should return, you can test it the following way:

`expect(YourModel.hauptdiagnose_filter(hauptdiagnose)).to eq([obj1, obj2])`